# BASH file name completion

Tags: bash, terminal

In BASH I can normally start typing a file name, then type TAB and it will give me some suggestions.

I have a list of files that look like this:

```
20130519114000_add_hstore.rb
20130615125517_create_sites.rb
20130616112833_create_delayed_jobs.rb
....
```

Is there a way I could type something like "*delayed" and then TAB (or something) to find "20130616112833_create_delayed_jobs.rb".

At the moment, sifting through those numbers at the start of the filenames is too much cognitive load :)

Comment: did you try using something like `ls | grep delayed` or `ls *delayed*`?

Comment: Excellent, had not tried `*delayed*` - this works very well thanks :)

Comment: Make a reply and I will mark it as the solution, if you like

Comment: or ls "\*delayed\*" ?  ....

Comment: @user537339: added this as answer per your request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use either:

```
ls *delayed*
```

or

```
ls | grep delayed
```

to filter list of files to what you want.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. The details can vary depending on your keyboard, and your Readline command bindings, and how you're logged into the system, and so on, but typically you can do this by typing `*delayed`, and then hitting `Alt+g` instead of `TAB`. (Search for `glob-complete-word` in [§8.4.8 "Some Miscellaneous [Readline] Commands" in *The Bash Reference Manual*](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Miscellaneous-Commands).)

Comment: +1.  BTW, on some terminals `prefix-meta (ESC)` works well if `Alt` cannot be used.